# Raspberry Pi not saving data on shutdown

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi currently running a web server and database. Recently, files have not been persisting over shutdowns. I discovered this issue last night when I was going to check on one of the new pages I had added to the webserver only to realize that the file I had added was not saved on the Pi and all of the pages I had edited recently had reverted to old versions of the pages.

I looked it up and it seemed like the fix was to run "sync" before running "sudo shutdown" and unplugging the device. I did that last night, expecting everything to be fine for when I rebooted the device today, but the Pi was back to how it had been originally last night, without any of the new edits or new files I had added to the device.

Any ideas on whats going on here?

Comment: It's running Raspbian Jesse if that helps

Comment: Have you tried changing the SD card? Maybe you have a faulty SD card.

Comment: How are you editing the files? Remotely or local? Are you using vim, nano, etc?

Comment: @bhazeroo the card had been working fine for the past 5 months, is there a chance it got messed up since then?

Comment: @MikeBoss editing and creating some files locally using nano, other files remotely